# Biguint < operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Hi I need help creating a < operator and Im not sure how.

```
#include "biguint.h"
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
biguint::biguint()
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++){
    data_[i]=0;
  }
}

biguint::biguint(const std::string &s){
  int templeng = s.length();
  for(size_t i = 0; i < templeng; i++){
    data_[i] = s[templeng -i - 1] -'0';
  }
  for(size_t i = templeng; i < CAPACITY; i++){
    data_[i]=0;
  }
}

unsigned short biguint::operator [](std::size_t pos) const{
  unsigned short i = 0;
  if(pos >= 0 && pos < CAPACITY){
    i = data_[pos];
  }
  return i;
}
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const biguint& b)
{
  for (int i = biguint::CAPACITY; i > 0; i--) {
    out<<b[i-1];
  }
  return out;
}
void biguint::operator += (const biguint & b){
  int k = 0;
  int temp = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++) {
    temp = data_[i]+b.data_[i];
    if(temp >= 10){
      data_[i] = temp-10;
      data_[i+1]+=1;
    }
    else{
      data_[i]=temp;
    }
  }
}
biguint operator + (const biguint & lhs, const biguint & rhs)
{
  int temp;
  bool remainder = false;
  std::string result = "";
  std::string reverse = "";
  if(lhs.CAPACITY != rhs.CAPACITY)
  {
    return biguint("0");
  }
  for(int i =0; i < (int)lhs.CAPACITY;i++)
  {
    temp = lhs[i]+rhs[i];
    if(remainder)
    {
      temp++;
      remainder = false;

    }
    if(temp<10)
    {
      result = result + std::to_string(temp);
    }

    else {
            result += std::to_string(temp - 10);
            remainder = true;
        }
  }
  for (int i = result.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      reverse += result[i];
  }

  return biguint(reverse);
}
int biguint::compare(const biguint & b) const
{
  return this->toStdString().compare(b.toStdString());
}
std::string biguint::toStdString() const
{
    bool start = false;
    std::string result = "";

    for (int i = (int) this->CAPACITY - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (this->data_[i] == 0 && !start) {
            if (this->CAPACITY == 1)
                result += std::to_string(this->data_[i]);
            continue;
        }

        else {
            start = true;
            result += std::to_string(this->data_[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}


bool operator < (const biguint & lhs, const biguint & rhs)
{

}
```

This my .cpp file Im kind of lost on how to create < operator. I have created the +,+=, and two string but I'm unsure of how to create the <. Im not sure how to access those numbers for example biguint one("233") how would i access that number

Comment: You have `biguint::compare` that you can place in there as `return lhs.compare(rhs) < 0;`

Comment: @lakeweb but wouldn't that do a lexicographic comparison? eg. 9 > 1000 in such a comparison right(given his implementation)?

Comment: Your `compare` says that 12 is less than 2, which seems odd. (A longer integer is greater than a shorter one.)

Comment: Hi @tangy, yes. I'm in error.

Comment: @molbdnilo how would I change it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tl;dr:** Try to compare digit by digit while handling mismatched length cases.

Say your given any 2 numbers:

```
num1 = 12345
num2 = 57632
```

The intuitive way for you to determine that which is bigger:

1. Compare them starting from the most significant digit(eg. here 5 > 1)
2. When equal compare the next significant digit(eg. if the numbers were `92` and `93`, you would have compared `2 < 3` to get your answer.

The only difference is here individual digits are stored in an array.

P.S. Your `compare` seems to do a lexicographic compare - Is that really what you want?

Comment: would i say something like lhs.data_[0]>rhs.data[0] how do i access the number?

Comment: I would fix the `compare` and use that in the free function. Assuming of course that `data_` is private(which it should be).

Comment: what do you mean free function? am a bit confused about compare

Comment: (1) Free function means a non-member function (2) For compare you could return 1 if greater, 0 if equal and -1 if unequal?

Comment: I see unfortunately I am required to use compare as a member function im not sure how to access those numbers to compare like the first number

Comment: how can i fix my compare function?

Comment: Write the correct compare which does numerical instead of lexicographic comparison. Do `lhs.compare(rhs)` in the `<` operator function.

Comment: put that in my function returns 1 but I'm doing "456"<"128" am honestly not too sure what to do to make it numerical comparison remove the stdtoString

Comment: stdToString does not make sense - The string ctor/internal representation are implementation details. Think about what a user of your class would want - A compare function matching that of a regular unsigned integer datatype.

Comment: am honestly not to sure what do do you have a source to help? I'm confused on what to do with the comparsion and how to actually compare the two and access those numebrs

Comment: I finally got it lhs.compare(rhs) < 0;

Comment: you could consider accepting if you found it helpful